# Google Dialogflow Smalltalk Stopped Providing Custom Answers

Tags: dialogflow-es

Agent Intents and Smalltalk were working for over 2 months then last week the small talk answers stopped using my specialized answers and went back to generic

I haven't made any modifications to the chatbot otherwise. Utilizing interaction with FB

```
{
  "responseId": "57643eeb-f9af-4d85-9e18-5ea62432bcc8-32138632",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "how are you?",
    "action": "smalltalk.greetings.how_are_you",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "I'm living my best life! How about you $NAME?",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "I'm living my best life! How about you $NAME?"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {},
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "en"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about Smalltalk language? Please see - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk

Comment: Im not using smalltalk language. I am referring to smalltalk which is a app within google dialogflow

Comment: @DavidMurray I am also facing the same problem. Were you able to resolve it?